# SymmetricDS Heartbeat Delay Time

Tags: symmetricds

I'm using bi-directional push mode with `sync_on_incoming_batch=1`.

Let say corp send heartbeat to `store-001`. Soon, `store-001` send heartbeat to `corp`. But the `node_id` in `sym_outgoing_batch` is `-1`.

Question:

1. How long heartbeat delay time (until it send heartbeat again)?
2. I read if `sync_on_incoming_batch=1` and after `corp` sent to `store-001`, the `store-001` doesn't send it back to `corp`. Is `node_id=-1` on `sym_outgoing_batch` the sign of it?
3. If number 2 is yes, how long the expiry time occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heartbeat is a symmetricDs internal message that's an indication if a target node is reachable. Delays are not fixed, but get prolonged in case of an unreachable target node.

`sync_on_incoming_batch` can't be set on a heartbeat message

`sym_outgoing_batch.node_id = -1` means that the extracted data hasn't been successfully routed to any nodes. It usually happens because there's no node belonging to such a node group that was supposed to be the target.

Comment: `sym_outgoing_batch.node_id = -1` but when i tracked down it use `router_id` from `store-001` to `corp`. How can route job fails to route node?

Comment: meh, just ignore it. no big deal

Comment: haha, I just want to find out why sometimes `AcknowledgeService - Could not find batch x to acknowledge as OK` and `PushService - Pushing to x again because the last push contained reload batches` are happened